# why does my function is returning data type None??: Python datatype None

Tags: python, pycharm, nonetype

This is my python code for printing an absolute number. My function is returning type `None`. I am not getting what I have done wrong. Please help me.

```
def n(num):
    if num<0:
        return (num*-1)

no = input("Enter a number: ")
print "Absolute Value is: "
print n(no)
```

Comment: If you don't explicitly return something from a function then python implicitly put a `return None` at the end.

Comment: Because you don't return anything when `num >= 0`, so the default is returned instead. The default is `None`.

Comment: what do you think happens if you call `n(42)`?

Comment: There already is an absolute value function `import math; return math.fabs(-42)`

Comment: Keep in mind that `input` returns a `string` so you will never return the absolute value from your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
def n(num):
    if num<0:
        return (num*-1)
    else:
        return num


no = input("Enter a number: ")
print "Absolute Value is: "
print n(no)
```

writing an else statement will return num >= 0

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

The `return` is on the condition. Try :

```
def n(num):
    if num<0:
        num *= -1
    return num

no = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print "Absolute Value is: "
print n(no)
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need your own function for absolute value...

```
no = input("Enter a number: ")
print "Absolute Value is: ", abs(no)
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans :) I didnt know about abs function ()

Comment: Yeah, there is a whole table of [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)