# Python 3 Not void function still returning None Type

Tags: python, function, nonetype

I'm writing an initial fruitful function with a return value int.
I then create a void function with a simple print statement in the body with no return value, therefore, None type.
However when I create a third function that calls the fruitful function in the body, therefore the third function will return a value it's still a None type.
I've read the stack previously questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228553/why-does-my-function-is-returning-data-type-none-python-datatype-none), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245175/python-none-passed-against-standard-types-functions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47785124/python-3-function-returns-none-type-yet-print-give-correct-output)
However, could not find a solution.

Here is my code:

```
def return_something():
    return 3

def return_void_test():
    print('VOID')

def return_void_filled():
    #This has inside a RETURN VALUE
    print(return_something())
    return_something()


 print(return_something()) 
 print(return_something)
 j = return_something()
 print(type(j),'\n')

 print(return_void_test())
 print(return_void_test)
 k = return_void_test()
 print(type(k),'\n')

 print(return_void_filled())
 print(return_void_filled)
 g = return_void_filled()
 print(type(g))
```

Here is the result:

```
3
<function return_something at 0x000001CEEF392E18>
<class 'int'> 

VOID
None
<function return_void_test at 0x000001CEF10247B8>
VOID
<class 'NoneType'> 

3
None
<function return_void_filled at 0x000001CEF133B6A8>
3
<class 'NoneType'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Why the third function still shows as a None Type when it should be int(as Returns a value int 3)?
Thanks

Comment: In Python, if there is no return statement an implicit return None is added to the end.

Comment: " I then create a void function" no you do not, there is no such thing as a void function, indeed, functions *always* return a value, and that value isn't typed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't returning anything in your third function. You're only calling a function that **does** return something. Simply add a `return`

```
def return_void_filled():
    #This has inside a RETURN VALUE
    print(return_something())
    return return_something()
```